# Satellite DVR: Cant play recording on computer

Tags: codec

I have a Satellite STB which saves .mpg files.

I can't play them through vlc and avidemux gives me a blurred output?

Is there any way I can edit these recordings?

EDIT: [Here is a link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24369006/CCTV%2014%5B10FEB2013-055546%5D.mpg) to a very short clip in this format (6.6MB).

[image]

mediainfo output:

```
General
Complete name                            : CCTV-11[02JUN2012-183712].mpg
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 3.94 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 43mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 473 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 234 (0xEA)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@Main
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Custom
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=12
Duration                                 : 1h 43mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 5 108 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 10 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.493
Stream size                              : 3.68 GiB (93%)

Audio
ID                                       : 192 (0xC0)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Duration                                 : 1h 43mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 256 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -921ms
Stream size                              : 189 MiB (5%)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think .mpg is just a container which can contain different codecs. To diagnose your problem, could you maybe post some more information on the video? Running [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download) and posting the output here will help people to answer your question.

Comment: @BartArondson done

Comment: OK, not sure what it might be... but googling around shows that someone else had [the same problem](http://www.networkedmediatank.com/showthread.php?tid=64799) and fixed it with a remux to mkv. As Avidemux is also showing you a weird output I'm guessing the stream might be damaged (no idea, just a guess). Look [here](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:projectx) on how to repair it.

Comment: @BartArondson ProjectX demuxed the video correctly, but the demuxed audio stutters constantly.. now i'm looking for a tool to demux the audio correctly

Comment: @BartArondson I added a link to an example file

Comment: The sample plays fine on my mac with [Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html), although it has some interlacing effects. Maybe you can use that program to play the video?

Comment: @BartArondson gah, works now - thanks for your help. The fact that you could play it fine gave me the clue that it might be a codec issue (see answer). Sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this has a stupid answer.

I installed the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package and avidemux opens this file fine now.

Looks like I didn't have the right codecs.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted, such that this question is marked as answered.